# Arduino project- print

Tags: arduino

```
#include <PS2Keyboard.h>


const int buttonPin = 4;

int buttonState = 0;


void setup() {

  pinMode (buttonPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {



buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println("In");

}

}
```

I simply want it to print In, but it keeps repeating In many times.

Maybe I am pressing the button longer, but I want the loop to run it once.

Comment: Storage is in the loop and outside your if case. Everything in the loop is... Looping you can use a variable that says your button high was acknowledge to work as a debouncer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion to you would be to add a delay to your code after the `Serial.print("Storage");`, like so:

```
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println("Storage");
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

What I suspect is happening is that even when you push the button quickly, the void loop goes through a number of times. To fix that, you add a delay of whatever time amount you need, so that if you press the button, you have time to let go before the code starts looping again.

Comment: This method worked perfectly fine for me! Thanks oakTree aka Groot!